# Sha1hash in Postman

Tags: postman

I have started to use Postman to test an API and also to learn more about coding, I am a novice, and have come into an issue.

I have declared multiple Global Variables which are used in my request to an endpoint however the endpoint requires a hash to be submitted which is a concatenation of multiple variables along with a textual key that i have been provide with, for example password,.

My question is how do I create this hash value to be submitted along with my request? I have tried multiple ways of declaring a variable and concatenating the various variables together along with my textual key, all to no avail I am afraid to say.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you may use pre-request script. In this script you can build your hash value (find the proper function in javascript) with your global variables and then update your request. To do so, use another global in your request, that you will update with your hash value at the end of your pre-request script.

Comment: I have updated the code I am using to be                                                 var sigString = "{{$MerchantName}}.{{$OrderNumber}}";
var token = CryptoJS.SHA1(sigString);
postman.setGlobalVariable("token",token);                                              The OrderNumber is a randomly generated GUID that i get PostMan to generated. A sha1 hash is being generated so I appear to  be on the right path at least